# Android Retrofit OAuth2 token refresh

Tags: android, retrofit2, oauth-2.0, okhttp

I am trying to implement OAuth2 in my android app using Retrofit. I have created the Authenticate and Refresh methods but am having issues in getting a request which fails with a 401 to refresh before then trying again.

My Rest Adapter is as follows

```
private Retrofit getRestAdapter() {
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.authenticator(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            public Request authenticate(Route route, final okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                refresh(new CallBack<UserAuthentication>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(UserAuthentication result) {
                        okhttp3.Response modifiedResponse = response;
                        modifiedResponse.request().newBuilder().header("access_token", result.getAuthToken()).build();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable error) {
                        Log.d("Error", "Couldn't refresh");
                    }
                });
                return null;
            }
        });
         if (restAdapter == null) {
             restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                     .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                     .client(builder.build())
                     .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                     .build();
         }
        return restAdapter;
    }
```

My aim in the authenticate method is to call the refresh method and then use the new access_token to send an updated version of the original request.

The refresh method is as follows

```
public void refresh(final CallBack<UserAuthentication> callBack) {
        OAuth = new UserAuthentication(mContext);
        Log.d("Refresh", "Token: " + OAuth.getRefreshToken());
        getApiService().refreshOAuth(OAuth.getUserId(), OAuth.getRefreshToken()).enqueue(new Callback<UserAuthentication>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserAuthentication> call, Response<UserAuthentication> response) {
                response.body().writeTokensPreferences(mContext);
                if (callBack != null) callBack.onResult(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserAuthentication> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error: " , "" + t.getMessage());
                if (callBack != null) callBack.onError(t);
            }
        });
    }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.